# will be on VS is on?

Tags: tense

Which is correct?

> The new schedule for the examination is on Tuesday, 23 March 2021

OR

> The new schedule for the examination will be on Tuesday, 23 March 2021

Comment: I would use 'The new date for the examination is...' A schedule is a _list_ of dates or times.

Answer (score 1):

The natural way to say this would be

> The new date for the examination is Tuesday 23 March 2021
> The new date for the examination will be Tuesday 23 March 2021

If you want to use the word scheduled you could say

> The examination is now scheduled for Tuesday 23 March 2021

The way your examples read to me suggests a possible interpretation that what will happen on Tuesday is that you will publish the new schedule for the examination rather than that is when the examination itself will take place.