# "It will be Ann’s birthday on Saturday." & "It is Ann’s birthday on Saturday."

Tags: phrase-meaning, time-reference

Are these sentences correct? Have they got the same meaning and similar usage?

> It will be Ann’s birthday on Saturday.
>
> It is Ann’s birthday on Saturday.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [will be on VS is on?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/278008/will-be-on-vs-is-on)

Comment: I can't find there an answer on my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It will be Ann’s birthday on Saturday.

> It is Ann’s birthday on Saturday.

Both examples are grammatical.  However, as a person's birthday does not change, *is* could be better.

On the other hand, if this is about Ann's birthday party, both suggestions below are similar.

> It will be Ann’s birthday [party] on Saturday.

> It is Ann’s birthday [party] on Saturday.